# Page numberin page x of y format in footer

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to show page numbers in Page x of y format. like 
page 1 of 10
page 2 of 10....

I am using the Itextsharp PDF tool to generate PDF using asp.net and C#.

Below is my code:

```
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 20, 10);
    string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "/pdf/myPdf" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".pdf";
    try
    {
        //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Create);
        //
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

        //Header Section
        string strImagePath = Server.MapPath("Images");
        string strReportName = oReportDTO.strReportName + " " + oReportDTO.oDateRange.FromDate.ToString(DateFormat);
        Chunk headerchunk = new Chunk(strReportName, new Font(1, 12.0f));
        HeaderFooter oHeader = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(headerchunk), false);
        oHeader.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        oHeader.Alignment = 1;
        doc.Header = oHeader;

        int NoOfReports=0;
        //Footer Section
        string name = "Logged in as : " + currentLoggedInUser.UserName + new string(' ', 70) + "Page : " + doc.PageNumber +"of";
        Chunk Footerchunk1 = new Chunk(name, new Font(1, 0.0f));
        HeaderFooter oFooter1 = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(Footerchunk1), true);
        oFooter1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        oFooter1.Alignment = 1;
        doc.Footer = oFooter1;
        iTextSharp.text.Image imgFooter = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(strImagePath + "/TransRisk Logo168x97.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imgFooter.ScaleAbsolute(80, 50);
        Chunk footerchunk = new Chunk(imgFooter, 260.0f, 0.0f);
        HeaderFooter oFooter = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(name),new Phrase(footerchunk));
        oFooter.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        doc.Footer = oFooter;


        doc.Open();//Open Document to write    

        Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 7);

        HtmlTable dt = customMatrixReport;

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Craete instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table
            int startColumnPosition = 1;
            int endColumnPosition = 13;//End Column number in Pdf Page
            NoOfReports = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((decimal)(dt.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 1) / endColumnPosition));//Count How many Pages to show
            int pageRowCount = 0;
            List<PdfPCell> lstHeaderCells = new List<PdfPCell>();
            PdfPTable oPdfTable = null;
            PdfPCell oPdfPCell = null;
            for (int report = 1; report <= NoOfReports; ++report)
            {
                doc.Add(oHeader);
                //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(


                int noOfColumns = -1;
                if (endColumnPosition > dt.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 1) { endColumnPosition = dt.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 1; noOfColumns = (endColumnPosition - startColumnPosition) + 2; oPdfTable = new PdfPTable(noOfColumns); oPdfTable.HeaderRows = 1; }
                else
                {
                    oPdfTable = new PdfPTable(14);
                    oPdfTable.HeaderRows = 1;

                    //Widths Count
                    noOfColumns = 14;
                }
                oPdfTable.TotalWidth = 650f;
                List<float> lstwidths = new List<float>();
                lstwidths.Add(100f);
                for (int i = 2; i <= noOfColumns; ++i)
                {
                    lstwidths.Add(80f);
                }
                oPdfTable.SetTotalWidth(lstwidths.ToArray());
                pageRowCount = 0;

                for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
                {
                    //PageRowCount
                    pageRowCount = pageRowCount + 1;
                    //Description celll
                    if (rows == 0 )
                    {
                        //Background color for table header
                        oPdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows].Cells[0].InnerText, new Font(1, 8.0f, 1, Color.WHITE))));
                        oPdfPCell.BackgroundColor = new Color(118, 147, 199);
                        oPdfTable.AddCell(oPdfPCell);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //background color for Table cells
                        oPdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows].Cells[0].InnerText,new Font(1, 8.0f))));
                        oPdfPCell.BackgroundColor = new Color(232, 237, 255);
                        oPdfTable.AddCell(oPdfPCell);
                    }

                    //for header cel
                    if (rows == 0)
                    {
                        lstHeaderCells.Add(oPdfPCell);
                    }
                    for (int column = startColumnPosition; column <= endColumnPosition; column++)
                    {

                        if (rows == 0)
                        {
                            oPdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows].Cells[column].InnerText, new Font(1, 8.0f, 1, Color.WHITE))));
                            oPdfPCell.BackgroundColor = new Color(118, 147, 199);
                            oPdfTable.AddCell(oPdfPCell);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oPdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows].Cells[column].InnerText, new Font(1, 8.0f))));
                            oPdfPCell.BackgroundColor = new Color(232, 237, 255);
                            oPdfPCell.Column.Alignment = 2;
                            oPdfTable.AddCell(oPdfPCell);

                        }

                        if (rows == 0)
                        {
                            lstHeaderCells.Add(oPdfPCell);
                        }
                    }
                    if (pageRowCount >= 40 && rows != (dt.Rows.Count - 1))
                    {
                        pageRowCount = 0; doc.Add(oPdfTable); doc.NewPage(); doc.Add(oHeader); oPdfTable = new PdfPTable(noOfColumns); oPdfTable.HeaderRows = 1; oPdfTable.SetTotalWidth(lstwidths.ToArray()); foreach (PdfPCell oHeaderCell in lstHeaderCells) { oPdfTable.AddCell(oHeaderCell); }
                    }
                }
                startColumnPosition = endColumnPosition + 1;
                endColumnPosition = endColumnPosition + 13;
                oPdfTable.SpacingBefore = 10;
                oPdfTable.SpacingAfter = 10;
                doc.Add(oPdfTable);
                //doc.NewPage();
            }

        }
        else
            doc.Add(oHeader);
```

Help me

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: i want to show page number, UserName and Image in footer for every page in pdf.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, have you tried applying the examples on adding page numbers from the iText web site? And what blocked you?

Comment: What id and version of iText are you using? Is this iTextSharp? There are significant differences in the code depending on that. Check your `packages.config`.